# Is there a maximum content size for option element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, dom, browser

I have a web app with a form in it. The form in turn has a `select` element with options containing a bunch of users' info, their names being set as the label/content of the `option` elements.

Now apparently one of the users' parents think it's fun to give their child a name with 3000 characters of gibberish in it.

I wouldn't want to make his life any harder than it is, but unfortunately I'll have to remove his account because the long name seems to introduce some interesting limitations on browsers that I didn't know about.
I started highly scientific testing [using this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aupbbjLL/16/) with a few browsers in two computers and found out that

- Chrome v50 (64bit) displayed a black box instead of the dropdown when the label length hit 1510
  [image: this is not what i ordered]
- FF v46 refused to open the dropdown at all when the content length was 2716
- IE v11 doesn't even break a sweat with tens of thousands of characters
- Chrome v49 was the least fun of all. It rendered the whole window **and all the other open tabs** fully black so I had to close them all and start again. Didn't bother to find the exact limit for that

It seems though that the actual limits are much more related to the content *width* and not the *length*, as changing the character from "a" to "i" using proportional font affected the results.

**The question**: is there a reason Chrome and FF flip out with content of this size? Is there a specific limit on how long/wide the option's label can be *(other than the subjective opinions about aesthetic/usable form inputs)*?

Comment: Are you using a database to store the parents/children names, etc?

Comment: Sure, but the question isn't really about whether or how I should limit the user's input lenths, I'm more interested in the *why* this happens. I wouldn't really like if some dropdown in the wild would crash all the open tabs just for clicking it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your specific question, but I do for your specific problem: Just limit the field length in the db. Your problem is solved. No *name* column should allow ~3,000 characters. Also limit the `input` length, and verify when you parse the form in the backend. Your question is rather about curiosity than anything. There are many ways to avoid this from ever happening.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome (v50 64bit) with over 1,000,000 characters. Though it took a long time load and a long time to console log the output. Perhaps this is related to your system as much as the browsers

Comment: @Turnip thanks for your commitment! It might indeed be about the system, but this question really sprang from a bug-report and I tested it with several computers, so I think its safe to assume it's not solely about *my* system but can be replicated in other environments as well. Could you share the fiddle you tried?

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/aupbbjLL/17/ . It was actually 10,000,510 !

Comment: @Turnip well, that was interesting, now it shows a white box for me instead of the black one I posted in the question. I guess that's progress... Still no content though on Chrome v50 64bit in Windows 10